# Show that degree sequence is graphic

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

We have to show that the degree sequence (n,n,n-1,n-1,...,3,3,2,2,1,1) is graphic for all n bigger or equal to 1. I used the technique where you delete the first degree (n) in the sequence and then for the next n degrees you substract one, but I get stuck at actually subtracting 1 from n degrees. Not sure if I’m on the right path.

Comment: Define "graphic."

Comment: Oh, I think my question has already been answered. Thanks David. Do you think I should delete this question from my account? I just started using this website.

Comment: @DaveWhyte You don't need to delete a question that has been marked as a duplicate, because it might help other people find that question. There's some automated deletion of closed questions that happens every so often, but I don't know off the top of my head if it will happen in this case or not. Regardless, you're fine - though as you use this site more, you'll get better at finding old questions rather than asking them again.